# C# or Java in command-line/scripting/interpreted environment?

Tags: c#, .net, scripting, programming-languages

So in Python on a unix environment, for example, we can open up python from terminal, start writing code and immediately run it to test some python library functions. Is there a similar commandline/scripting environment for C# or Java (perhaps a plugin to the IDE?)? Such a tool would seem pretty useful for experimenting with something like the System library.

Relatedly, I read that some versions of Python are compiled into bytecode before being executed by a virtual environment, which sounds like Java and C#. But, the Python program I open up in terminal and start typing code into has to be interpreted, right? So based on principle, it seems like it is possible to write a C# or Java interpreter. So I'm not sure why I just haven't seen anyone interacting with C# or Java on the commandline the way they do with Python.

Thanks.

Comment: C# and java need to be compiled before being interpreted

Comment: F# repl is quite good for experimenting

Comment: @Anonymous Sure, but Python, Scala, Haskell, and many other languages too. They just hide it better.

Comment: @Anonymous: Neither C# nor Java are interpreted. They are compiled into byte code upon build time and from byte code into machine code at run time by the JIT compiler

Comment: @delnan You're getting to the question I'm trying to convey, which is since many so-called scripting languages are also compiled, why hasn't C# or Java added a similar option, which I believe would be pretty useful?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth:- Sure, and the process of converting java instruction set by jvm into some IA32 specific instruction set is called _________????I think the term interpretation suits here ;Done after compilation :)

Comment: @Anonymous: Nope. That's called [**just in time compilation**](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=jit%20compilation&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEwQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FJust-in-time_compilation&ei=_topUPKvMo6RswbTzICgAQ&usg=AFQjCNFtXETVqNjfDJfhb8L4giPNFTqwsw&cad=rja), done by the JIT compiler. Technically, there is a huge difference between JIT compilation and interpretation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For .NET, if LINQPad is overkill for you, try the [RunNET](http://www.mobzystems.com/tools/runnet/) command-line package. It requires that you load script files instead of interactive typing, but lets you leverage more languages.

Answer (score 7):

For .NET there is [LINQPad](http://www.linqpad.net/). It supports C#, VB.NET and F#.

The name suggests that it is only for LINQ but you can execute any code in there. There is no need for a database.

Comment: Can you to this through the command line, or does one need the GUI?

Comment: If you want to write LINQPad scripts, you can run them later from the command-line using LINQPadRunner (https://github.com/mcintyre321/LINQPadRunner). Otherwise, you have to use the GUI. I don't really see how that could be a downside, though...why would you ever want to write C# code using just the command prompt when a text editor is easily available?

Answer (score 1):

The ability to explore .NET types was one of the reasons I originally started learning F#, since it has an Interactive environment (in Visual Studio, click on View > Other Windows > F# Interactive.)  Upon digging deeper into F# I have found it to be one of my favorite programming languages.

Anyways, you may want to look at it.  It won't take long to figure out the basic syntax, and once you've got it you can explore various .NET objects in the Interactive Environment, if you don't want to wait for Roslyn.

For a tutorial, check out this page: http://www.tryfsharp.org/Tutorials.aspx